# How can I get actual query from MongoCollection?

Tags: java, mongodb

I using a MongoCollection as following code :

```
MongoDatabase conn = getMongoConnection(DbName);
MongoCollection collection = conn.getConnection(CollectionName);

List<BasicDBObject> query = new ArrayList();

if (searchKey.containsKey("filter1")) {
   String filter1= (String) searchKey.get("filter1");
   query.add(new BasicDBObject("filter1", filter1));
}

if (searchKey.containsKey("filter2")) {
   String filter2= (String) searchKey.get("filter2");
   query.add(new BasicDBObject("filter2", filter2));
}

int rowAmount = (int) collection.count(new BasicDBObject("$and", query));
```

rowAmount gets the correct amount of data, but I want to know an actual query when it got the result. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 0):

You can see actual queries sent to the server via [command monitoring](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/driver/reference/monitoring/).